# How to get the linked items of a work item in Azure DevOps

Tags: azure-devops

I am working with the Azure APIs and the VisualStudio.Services.Client.

My goal is to get a list of test Cases associated with a User Story, so far I'm here:

```
 VssConnection connection = new VssConnection(new Uri("https://{myOrg}.visualstudio.com"),
            new VssBasicCredential("UserName","SuperSecretPassword"));

        WorkItemTrackingHttpClient witClient = connection.GetClient<WorkItemTrackingHttpClient>();

        var ticket =  witClient.GetWorkItemAsync(1234).Result;
```

Which returns me my user Story.

Question:
I want to get at any linked items to this to find my Test Cases, but can't see any way to do this through the UI (so i can call the query) or via the APIs directly.

Any help would be really appreciated!

Comment: Similar question which uses the WorkItems endpoint in the WorkItemsTracking API with the `expand` parameter set to `relations`: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59275593/azure-devops-get-commits-linked-to-a-work-item-via-the-rest-api (it should be fairly straightforward to find the corrsponding method in the client you're using).
I'm linking to it because it avoids using WIQL which may be preferable for people, though the downside is you'll then need to filter the results to just links to Test Cases and then do another query to extract the target of these items. So maybe WIQL is better...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Personally I like to use WIQL Queries to retrieve data from Azure DevOps. It is very flexible and it could be used in any situation.

This example below is made for an Azure DevOps Widget. (javascript)

```
var wiqlQuery = `
SELECT
    [System.Id],
    [System.Title],
    [System.WorkItemType]
FROM workitemLinks
WHERE
    (
        [Source].[System.TeamProject] = @project
        AND [Source].[System.WorkItemType] = 'User Story'
    )
    AND (
        [System.Links.LinkType] = 'System.LinkTypes.Hierarchy-Forward'
    )
    AND (
        [Target].[System.TeamProject] = @project
        AND [Target].[System.WorkItemType] = 'Test Case'
    )
MODE (Recursive)`;

witClient.queryByWiql({ query: wiqlQuery }).then(function(result){
    // Your Code
});
```

You should keep in mind that the LinkType in important in this query.

Here you can find detailed information about the relation types: [Link type reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/queries/link-type-reference?view=vsts)

Here you can find more information about [WIQL queries](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/queries/wiql-syntax?view=vsts)

Here you can find the detailed information about the [Azure DevOps Rest API for WIQL Queries](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wit/wiql/query%20by%20wiql?view=azure-devops-rest-5.0)

If you have a query in Azure DevOps and you want to export it as WIQL query, you can use this [marketplace extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ottostreifel.wiql-editor)

Comment: Thanks so much, this is great! I get an error on "FROM workitemLinks". Have you got a link or guide on how to get the table names, or an explorer?

Comment: I removed a `,` in the answer, this should solve the error. Beside this I added an Azure DevOps marketplace extension in my answer. You can use it to easily change and build your WIQL queries.