# Azure DevOps get commits linked to a work item via the REST API

Tags: git, powershell, rest, azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

Is there a way to get Git Commits that are linked to a work item given only the work item ID?

[image]

I'm using PowerShell and [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wit/work%20items/get%20work%20item?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1) URI to get work items, but I don't see any of the linked commits on the returned object.  I also don't see any documentation on how to get these links.

```
$Results = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri "http://azuredevops/azuredevops/Collection/Project/_apis/wit/workitems?api-version=5.1&ids=1" -Method "GET" -UseDefaultCredentials | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Value
$Results.fields
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are very close to the correct solution.

The commits which linked to the work item is **relation** of work item. So, here, you need to specify `$expand` in API to get the corresponding commits content.

```
Get https://dev.azure.com/{org name}/{project name}/_apis/wit/workitems/{id}?$expand=relations&api-version=5.1
```

Then you would see the commits in `relations` part of the response body:

[image]

Comment: I'm adding this comment because I came in a little differently, and Google didn't get me here. This approach is also how you would get associated pull requests and related work items. They are just different relation types.